# Fail to write/read cookie with jQuery-cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I need to write and read a cookie and I'd like to use the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

However I cannot manage to store a cookie and read it back.

Here's a MWE

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.cookie('aCookie','aValue');
        console.log($.cookie('aCookie'));
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect to see `aValue` printed out in the console, whereas it prints `null`, i.e. the cookie has not been found.

I feel there is something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you using this [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)? There are a lot of them, please list what one you are using. Are you testing it on a server? Are cookies enabled?

Comment: Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jNvJQ/1/

Comment: Works perfectly for me, do you have cookies disabled or something? jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/EjAwe/

Comment: In the question there's already a link to the plug-in I'm using, could be some specific default settings that I have? All tests provided by the plugin developer run smoothly in the same browser (Chrome)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I missed that link, I hate how stackoverflow removes the underline! Are you running it on a server or file protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that the url in your browser points to local file so it is `file:///C:/some/path.html`

Chrome does not allow saving of cookies on the local files. Cookies are strictly a HTTP mechanism (RFC 2109)

You can enable them with the command line flag `--enable-file-cookies`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the flag you mentioned!

Comment: It worked using the flag. On OSX the full command to run Chrome passing the flag is `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --enable-file-cookies`. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not running the file from file://. Cookies are set by a server and I've had issues in the past if running off the file system

Comment: bingo! I'm stupid and I wasn't running it on a web server. Thank you for helping me finding it out. Merry Christmas!